# Copy files from one path to another path in c#

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, create-directory

If 
`frompath = "c:\\progfiles\\mobileapp\\es-gl\\a.dll"` 
and 
`topath = "c:\\progfiles\\mobileapp\\es-gl\\a.dll"`

I want to copy file from `frompath` to `topath`.
If `topath` does not exist, then the directories and sub directories must get created and the file a.dll must copy from `frompath` to `topath`. I am using c# .net Compact Framework.

Comment: I know to copy files from one path to other path. My doubt is if es-gl folder does not exist in the destination path, that needs to be created. The code must work well though if we have many folders to be created in the destination path. If I get some sample code, that will be useful.

Comment: @BadhriRavikumar - Verify the folder exists, if it does not exist, create it then copy the file to the folder.

Comment: Compact Framework target devices (i.e. Window CE) don't have lettered drives, so any path starting with "c:\" is already an invalid path.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are after the System.IO namespace. Using File.Copy can provide the solution. 
And Directory.Exists / create can make the directory is not existing.

```
var fileName = "tmp.txt";
var from = @"c:\temp\" + fileName;
var to = @"c:\temp\1\";
if (!Directory.Exists(to))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(to);

File.Copy(from, to + fileName);
```

You can go for FileInfo aswell. (Also in the System.IO namespace)

```
var file = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\tmp.txt");
var to = @"c:\temp\1\";
if (!Directory.Exists(to))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(to);

file.CopyTo(to + file.Name);
```

Comment: The problem here is if "c:\temp\1\" exists, then a folder named tmp.txt is created. That must not happen.

Comment: Ya. This will work out. I have one doubt. If suppose I have to="c:\temp\1\tmp.txt". How can I get "c:\temp\1\" alone in a seperate variable.?

Comment: Thinking of "c:\temp\1\tmp.txt" as a FileInfo you can use var file = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\1\tmp.txt"); file.Directory will now give you "c:\temp\1".